# For loop in r using summation

Tags: r

I have this,

```
sum(x^i)
```

with i being greater than or equal to 1.

How can I create a `for` loop in R for this summation?
In other words, how do I format this summation in R?

Comment: You don't need a loop for this. If `i` is constant `i = 2` and `x = 1:10`, `sum(x^i)` should work directly.

Comment: What is `x` .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `x` and `i` are vectors you may use `for` loop as -

```
x <- 1:10
i <- 1:10
result <- 0

for(e in i) {
  result <- result + sum(x^e)
}
result
```

If any of `x` or `i` goes to infinity, then the `result` would always be infinity.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed x and infinite `n`,

```
x <- 0.1 # You may change x
s <- 0
n <- 0
while(n < 100) { #If you want inf, let n >=0 then R will freeze recommend large number...
  s <- s + x^(n)
  n<-n+1
}
s
```